# fuse: missing mountpoint parameter

Tags: mount, nautilus, fuse

I have a problem openning remote files with sublime.
I learn that sublime needs local files, so i need gvfs to work. But the ./gvfs folder is empty after I connect to server via nautilus.

How to make this work? I have 2 devices, first one works, on this one don't.

Some comand to help:

```
$ strace -ft /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-fuse -r
```

The result:

```
13:17:13 execve("/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-fuse", ["/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-fuse", "-r"], [/* 73 vars */]) = 0
13:17:13 brk(NULL)                      = 0xbf1000
13:17:13 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f879d94b000
13:17:13 access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/tls/x86_64/libgvfscommon.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffd5474cf30) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/tls/libgvfscommon.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/tls", 0x7ffd5474cf30) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/x86_64/libgvfscommon.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/x86_64", 0x7ffd5474cf30) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
13:17:13 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360%\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
13:17:13 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=245912, ...}) = 0
13:17:13 mmap(NULL, 2341656, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f879d4ec000
13:17:13 mprotect(0x7f879d522000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
13:17:13 mmap(0x7f879d722000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x36000) = 0x7f879d722000
13:17:13 close(3)                       = 0
13:17:13 open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgio-2.0.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
13:17:13 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=120633, ...}) = 0
13:17:13 mmap(NULL, 120633, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f879d92d000
13:17:13 close(3)                       = 0
13:17:13 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
13:17:13 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200X\3\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
13:17:13 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1599368, ...}) = 0
13:17:13 mmap(NULL, 3701416, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f879d164000
13:17:13 mprotect(0x7f879d2e4000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
13:17:13 mmap(0x7f879d4e4000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x180000) = 0x7f879d4e4000
13:17:13 mmap(0x7f879d4ea000, 6824, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f879d4ea000
13:17:13 close(3)                       = 0
13:17:13 open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgobject-2.0.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
13:17:13 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\257\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
13:17:13 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=339000, ...}) = 0
13:17:13 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f879d92c000
13:17:13 mmap(NULL, 2436840, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f879cf11000
13:17:13 mprotect(0x7f879cf63000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
13:17:13 mmap(0x7f879d162000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x51000) = 0x7f879d162000
13:17:13 close(3)                       = 0
13:17:13 open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libglib-2.0.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
13:17:13 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`\250\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
13:17:13 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1115136, ...}) = 0
13:17:13 mmap(NULL, 3212632, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f879cc00000
13:17:13 mprotect(0x7f879cd0f000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
13:17:13 mmap(0x7f879cf0e000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x10e000) = 0x7f879cf0e000
13:17:13 mmap(0x7f879cf10000, 1368, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f879cf10000
13:17:13 close(3)                       = 0
13:17:13 open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libfuse.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfuse.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
13:17:13 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260o\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
13:17:13 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=243832, ...}) = 0
13:17:13 mmap(NULL, 2339104, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f879c9c4000
13:17:13 mprotect(0x7f879c9ee000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
13:17:13 mmap(0x7f879cbed000, 77824, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x29000) = 0x7f879cbed000
13:17:13 close(3)                       = 0
13:17:13 open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
13:17:13 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0a\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
13:17:13 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=138760, ...}) = 0
13:17:13 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f879d92b000
13:17:13 mmap(NULL, 2212904, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f879c7a7000
13:17:13 mprotect(0x7f879c7bf000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
13:17:13 mmap(0x7f879c9be000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x17000) = 0x7f879c9be000
13:17:13 mmap(0x7f879c9c0000, 13352, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f879c9c0000
13:17:13 close(3)                       = 0
13:17:13 open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
13:17:13 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\t\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
13:17:13 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1864888, ...}) = 0
13:17:13 mmap(NULL, 3967392, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f879c3de000
13:17:13 mprotect(0x7f879c59d000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
13:17:13 mmap(0x7f879c79d000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1bf000) = 0x7f879c79d000
13:17:13 mmap(0x7f879c7a3000, 14752, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f879c7a3000
13:17:13 close(3)                       = 0
13:17:13 open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgmodule-2.0.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
13:17:13 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0p\21\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
13:17:13 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14656, ...}) = 0
13:17:13 mmap(NULL, 2109848, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f879c1da000
13:17:13 mprotect(0x7f879c1dd000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
13:17:13 mmap(0x7f879c3dc000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f879c3dc000
13:17:13 close(3)                       = 0
13:17:13 open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
13:17:13 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360\35\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
13:17:13 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=104824, ...}) = 0
13:17:13 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f879d92a000
13:17:13 mmap(NULL, 2199880, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f879bfc0000
13:17:13 mprotect(0x7f879bfd9000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
13:17:13 mmap(0x7f879c1d8000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x18000) = 0x7f879c1d8000
13:17:13 close(3)                       = 0
13:17:13 open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
13:17:13 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260Z\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
13:17:13 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=130224, ...}) = 0
13:17:13 mmap(NULL, 2234080, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f879bd9e000
13:17:13 mprotect(0x7f879bdbd000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
13:17:13 mmap(0x7f879bfbc000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1e000) = 0x7f879bfbc000
13:17:13 mmap(0x7f879bfbe000, 5856, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f879bfbe000
13:17:13 close(3)                       = 0
13:17:13 open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libresolv.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
13:17:13 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P9\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
13:17:13 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=101200, ...}) = 0
13:17:13 mmap(NULL, 2206280, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f879bb83000
13:17:13 mprotect(0x7f879bb9a000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
13:17:13 mmap(0x7f879bd9a000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x17000) = 0x7f879bd9a000
13:17:13 mmap(0x7f879bd9c000, 6728, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f879bd9c000
13:17:13 close(3)                       = 0
13:17:13 open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libffi.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
13:17:13 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360\27\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
13:17:13 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=31104, ...}) = 0
13:17:13 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f879d929000
13:17:13 mmap(NULL, 2127368, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f879b97b000
13:17:13 mprotect(0x7f879b982000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
13:17:13 mmap(0x7f879bb81000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7f879bb81000
13:17:13 close(3)                       = 0
13:17:13 open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libpcre.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
13:17:13 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000\25\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
13:17:13 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=456632, ...}) = 0
13:17:13 mmap(NULL, 2552072, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f879b70b000
13:17:13 mprotect(0x7f879b779000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
13:17:13 mmap(0x7f879b979000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6e000) = 0x7f879b979000
13:17:13 close(3)                       = 0
13:17:13 open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
13:17:13 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240\r\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
13:17:13 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14608, ...}) = 0
13:17:13 mmap(NULL, 2109680, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f879b507000
13:17:13 mprotect(0x7f879b50a000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
13:17:13 mmap(0x7f879b709000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f879b709000
13:17:13 close(3)                       = 0
13:17:13 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f879d928000
13:17:13 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f879d927000
13:17:13 mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f879d925000
13:17:13 arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f879d925800) = 0
13:17:13 mprotect(0x7f879c79d000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
13:17:13 mprotect(0x7f879b709000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
13:17:13 mprotect(0x7f879c9be000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
13:17:13 mprotect(0x7f879b979000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
13:17:13 mprotect(0x7f879bb81000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
13:17:13 mprotect(0x7f879bd9a000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
13:17:13 mprotect(0x7f879bfbc000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
13:17:13 mprotect(0x7f879c1d8000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
13:17:13 mprotect(0x7f879cf0e000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
13:17:13 mprotect(0x7f879c3dc000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
13:17:13 mprotect(0x7f879cbed000, 73728, PROT_READ) = 0
13:17:13 mprotect(0x7f879d162000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
13:17:13 mprotect(0x7f879d4e4000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
13:17:13 mprotect(0x7f879d722000, 20480, PROT_READ) = 0
13:17:13 mprotect(0x607000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
13:17:13 mprotect(0x7f879d94d000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
13:17:13 munmap(0x7f879d92d000, 120633) = 0
13:17:13 set_tid_address(0x7f879d925ad0) = 4614
13:17:13 set_robust_list(0x7f879d925ae0, 24) = 0
13:17:13 rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0x7f879c7acba0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f879c7b83e0}, NULL, 8) = 0
13:17:13 rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0x7f879c7acc30, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f879c7b83e0}, NULL, 8) = 0
13:17:13 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
13:17:13 getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
13:17:13 statfs("/sys/fs/selinux", 0x7ffd5474d740) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 statfs("/selinux", 0x7ffd5474d740) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13:17:13 brk(NULL)                      = 0xbf1000
13:17:13 brk(0xc12000)                  = 0xc12000
13:17:13 open("/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY) = 3
13:17:13 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
13:17:13 read(3, "nodev\tsysfs\nnodev\trootfs\nnodev\tr"..., 1024) = 359
13:17:13 read(3, "", 1024)              = 0
13:17:13 close(3)                       = 0
13:17:13 futex(0x7f879cf10428, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
13:17:13 futex(0x7f879cf10428, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
13:17:13 open("/dev/null", O_RDWR)      = 3
13:17:13 close(3)                       = 0
13:17:13 write(2, "fuse: missing mountpoint paramet"..., 35fuse: missing mountpoint parameter
) = 35
13:17:13 exit_group(1)                  = ?
13:17:13 +++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: I did some research and i had to set some permisions to **fusermount** (fusemount - notice the 'r').  
`$ cd /bin \ sudo chmod 4755 fusermount`  ---- This works for **Ubuntu 16.04**